Struggling to Achieve 60fps Using Blackfly S BFS-U3-16S2M Cameras for Motion Detection
Overview:
I'm using two Blackfly S BFS cameras to detect mosquito movements. After detecting movement, the cameras record for additional time, retrieve their circular buffer, and save the video. The cameras are synchronized via GPIO. The cameras are controlled using a Python wrapper library called EasyPySpin that allows me to configure some camera properties and also use OpenCV to perform motion detection.
The official Python library created by the camera manufacturers to control and configure these cameras is called Spinnaker. I'm not using Spinnaker because I could not figure out how to make OpenCV compatible with the image format outputted by the Spinnaker library.
Problem:
I'm struggling to achieve 60fps at a resolution of 1440x1080, even though the camera specs from the official manufacturer website state that 226fps at 1440x1080 in Mono8 is possible. When I try recording at 60fps at this resolution, it usually takes 12-13 seconds to record 600 frames (it should take 10 seconds at 60fps).
System Load:

CPU usage caps at around 550%
Memory usage caps at 20%

What I've Tried:

Using threads: This had some improvement, reducing the recording time to 11-12 seconds for 600 frames. However, I might be using threading incorrectly due to my lack of experience with it. I also don't fully understand how one specifies individual CPU cores to handle different threads (if that's even how it works).
Lowering the resolution: This obviously improved the frame rate, but I still want to achieve at least ~200fps at 1440x1080.

PC Specs:

Motherboard: B650 AORUS ELITE AX V2
GPU: RTX 4070
Processor: Ryzen 7 7700x
Cameras: Blackfly B BFS-U3-16S2M (2 units)

Software Environment:

OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04.4
Python: 3.10.12
Spinnaker: 4.0.0.116
Spinnaker-Python: 4.0.0.116
EasyPySpin: 2.0.1
OpenCV-Python: 4.10.0.84
NumPy: 1.26.4

Current motion detection script:
import cv2
import EasyPySpin
import time
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from collections import deque

# OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04.4
# Python: 3.10.12
# spinnaker: 4.0.0.116
# spinnaker-python: 4.0.0.116
# EasyPySpin: 2.0.1
# opencv-python: 4.10.0.84
# numpy: 1.26.4


# BEFORE SYNCHRONIZATION:
# 500x500 works with 200fps
# 1440x1080 works with <=75fps

# AFTER SYNCHRONIZATION:
# 1440X1080 with <= 40fps

serial_number_0 = "24122966"  # primary camera serial number
serial_number_1 = "24122965"  # secondary camera serial number
cap = EasyPySpin.SynchronizedVideoCapture(serial_number_0, serial_number_1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 100)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out_0 = None
out_1 = None
buffer_size = 1000
additional_frame_size = 1000
additional_frames_0 = deque(maxlen=additional_frame_size)
additional_frames_1 = deque(maxlen=additional_frame_size)
ring_buffer_0 = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)
ring_buffer_1 = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 100)
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE))

def detect_motion(frame, back_sub, kernel, min_contour_area, i):
    fg_mask = back_sub.apply(frame)
    fg_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(fg_mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    fg_mask = cv2.medianBlur(fg_mask, 5)
    _, fg_mask = cv2.threshold(fg_mask, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(fg_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]

    if len(areas) == 0:
        cv2.imshow(f"frame-{i}", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            return None
    else:
        max_index = np.argmax(areas)
        if areas[max_index] > min_contour_area:
            return contours[max_index]
    return None

def motion_detection():
    sleep(5)
    print("Starting motion detection. Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
    global out_0
    global out_1
    prev_x = None
    recording = False
    frame_counter = 0

    # INCREASE varThreshold = LESS SENSITIVE MOTION DETECTION
    back_sub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=700, varThreshold=50, detectShadows=True)
    # INCREASE KERNEL SIZE FOR MORE AGGRESSIVE NOISE REDUCTION
    kernel = np.ones((30, 30), np.uint8)
    # DETERMINES THE CONTOUR SIZE TO BE CONSIDERED AS VALID MOTION
    # ONLY CONTOURS WITH AN AREA OF 1000 PIXELS OR MORE WILL BE CONSIDERED AS VALID MOTION.
    min_contour_area = 100

    while True:
        read_values = cap.read()
        for i, (ret, frame) in enumerate(read_values):
            if not ret:
                print("Error: Failed to capture image")
                break
            if not recording:
                if i == 0:
                    ring_buffer_0.append(frame)
                elif i == 1:
                    ring_buffer_1.append(frame)

            frame_copy = np.copy(frame)
            if not recording:
                contour = detect_motion(frame_copy, back_sub, kernel, min_contour_area, i)

            if contour is not None:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                x2 = x + int(w / 2)
                y2 = y + int(h / 2)

                cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
                cv2.circle(frame_copy, (x2, y2), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                text = f"x: {x2}, y: {y2}"
                cv2.putText(frame_copy, text, (x2 - 10, y2 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

                cv2.imshow(f"frame-{i}", frame_copy)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break

                if prev_x is not None and x2 < prev_x and not recording:
                    print("Motion Detected!")
                    print("Start: ", datetime.now().strftime("%Y%-m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
                    start_time = time.time()
                    recording = True
                    frame_counter = 0
                    frame_height, frame_width = frame.shape[:2]
                    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_")
                    print(frame_width, frame_height)
                    out_0 = cv2.VideoWriter(f'motion_detection_{timestamp}_0.avi', fourcc, 100.0, (frame_width, frame_height), isColor=False)
                    out_1 = cv2.VideoWriter(f'motion_detection_{timestamp}_1.avi', fourcc, 100.0, (frame_width, frame_height), isColor=False)
                prev_x = x2

            if recording:
                if i == 0:
                    additional_frames_0.append(frame)
                elif i == 1:
                    additional_frames_1.append(frame)
                frame_counter += .5 
                if frame_counter >= additional_frame_size:
                    recording = False
                    print("End: ", datetime.now().strftime("%Y%-m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])
                    print("Finished recording. Retrieving buffer and saving video...")
                    print("Elapsed time:", time.time() - start_time)
                    for frame in ring_buffer_0:
                        out_0.write(frame)
                    for frame in additional_frames_0:
                        out_0.write(frame)
                    for frame in ring_buffer_1:
                        out_1.write(frame)
                    for frame in additional_frames_1:
                        out_1.write(frame)
                    out_0.release()
                    out_1.release()
                    print("Video Saved!")
                    additional_frames_0.clear()
                    additional_frames_1.clear()
                    ring_buffer_0.clear()
                    ring_buffer_1.clear()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:    
        motion_detection()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping motion detection.")
    finally:
        cap.release()
        if out_1 is not None and out_0 is not None:
            out_1.release()
            out_0.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print("Closing camera and resetting...")


Given that the specs indicate achieving around 200fps at 1440x1080 should be possible, my question is: What is bottlenecking this system? The hardware shouldn't struggle so much with processing since the PC is pretty powerful, so I'm thinking it might be inefficiencies in my code. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Let me know if there's any other info I should provide.
Edit: Removed motion detection during video recording and removed the script with threading as I'm not using multi-threading anymore.

I don't know if you have tried this but to identify a bottleneck, you can use the perf_counter from the time python module. You can monitor precisely the time taken by each step. you can surround a bunch of lines with a t1 = time.perf_counter() and t2 = time.perf_counter(), and get the time it take to execute these lines by doing t2 - t1.

60 FPS means you have 16.6 milliseconds per iteration. Each iteration you handle two frames, for each you may call cv2.waitKey(1). The time specified is the lower bound, just this one function wastes at least 2 milliseconds, likely more per iteration, not really doing much useful work. All the drawing also seems to be only useful for visualization, which doesn't seem to be a primary goal (and certainly doesn't need to run at 60fps or faster). That's definitely something to decouple from the processing loop.

Using perf_counter, I determined that my detect_motion function takes around 0.007 seconds to execute for each frame, which adds significant processing time at 60 FPS. I also removed all visualizations and previews, as suggested by @Dan Mašek, which helped reduce the processing time slightly. I can now reach up to 60 FPS with a resolution of 1440x1080, but ideally, I want 100+ FPS. Additionally, I modified the code so that motion detection is not performed during video recording. Any suggestions on how I can decrease the processing time in the detect_motion function?

At this point, I'd move to a more sophisticated measurement method, a profiler that can give you timings at a statement level. Ideally one that can handle binary Python modules like OpenCV and numpy properly. Nice one I came a cross recently was https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene (just ignore the AI stuff). | I would be a good idea to [edit] the question, and update it with your most recent changes.

Some observations, although probably not very significant. First of all, you're calling findContours with cv2.RETR_TREE, yet you immediately discard the hierarchy component of the result. If you don't need it, don't ask for it. | Second, you're looking for the contour with the largest area. Hence, you're really only interested in the extreme outer contours in the image (If contour A fits inside contour B, then A must have a smaller area than B). Therefore, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL would seem appropriate.

Have you actually done the math on this? 1440x1080 at 200 fps even at one byte per pixel is 300 MB/s.  That's very nearly the practical limit for a USB 3 device.  Further, findContours is an expensive operation.  Have you measured how much time it takes?  I get the feeling you're just complaining about the performance without having done any instrumentstion.

Some more thoughts. Don't discard the idea of multithreading, having the capture stage asynchronous would definitely help, and OpenCV isn't very good at that AFAIK. The way I understand it, you want to capture at the highest possible frame rate. Question is, do you need to perform the detection at that rate as well? Would doing it ever second frame still work? Do you need to use the full frame, or could you use a smaller ROI? Would the detection still work well enough even at half the resolution? Etc.

@TimRoberts Yeah, that seems to fit with the "226fps at 1440x1080 in Mono8 is possible" ... all fingers crossed, and the planets aligned juuuuust right ;)

Yes.  If you are bus limited, then it doesn't matter how many threads you fire.  You can't pull bytes through any faster than that.

if this involves OpenCV's VideoCapture at all, you'll probably get its "convert to RGB/BGR" feature (converts from YUV or whatever), which takes additional time. you can disable that but then you'll get raw byte buffers instead of an image. some gray8 format is easy enough to handle.
